# contenteditable div not editable

Tags: html, editor, contenteditable

I am trying to create a basic editor with small custom tools.

When document get ready I create a div with contenteditable="true" attr and append it below the textarea and I hide the textarea.
And it is being created fine.

When I click on that div it do not get focus and I cannot type anything there. But when I try to add some style to that div using inspect element tool. And I click on that div again then it works.

Here is my code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".text-format-wrapper").length > 0){
      _editor_init();
    }
  });
  function _editor_init(){
    $(".text-format-wrapper").each(function(){
      var filterType = $(this).find(".filter-list").val();
      var filterEnable = false;
      for(var i in Drupal.settings.editor_filter){
        if(Drupal.settings.editor_filter[i] == filterType){
          filterEnable = true;
        }
      }
      var textareaObj = $(this).find('textarea')
      if(filterEnable){
        addEditor(textareaObj);
      }else{
        removeEditor(textareaObj);
      }
    });
  }
  function addEditor(textareaObj){
    if(textareaObj.closest(".form-textarea-wrapper").find(".editor").length == 0){
      var content = textareaObj.val();
      var d = document.createElement("div");
      d.className = 'editor';
      d.id = 'editor';
      d.contentEditable = "true";
      d.innerText = content;
      $('.form-textarea-wrapper').prepend(d);
      textareaObj.hide();
    }
```

I am preparing this in Drupal module.
Please help on this.

Thank you

Comment: Please include code in question.

Comment: I found the issue with that but not found the solution yet.
I have touchswipe.js file which is creating some problem. When I remove that js file. It works good but with js file it do not.